# Merge 2 CSV files with no common column

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 csv files( 2 million each) with below structure

```html
first.csv
h1,h2
2,3
4,5
```

```html
second.csv
h3,h4
5,6
7,8
```

I want to merge these 2 csv index wise column like below

```html
merged.csv
h1,h2,h3,h4
2,3,5,6
4,5,7,8
```

Comment: If you have to do this just once, open both in Excel, copy/paste and save.

Comment: csv files size is 7 million each

Comment: You can read csv with Pandas to two varriables. Then you can use Pandas concat those to dataframes.  There are exmaples here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html

Comment: Either you are processing those files with Excel, or with a custom program. In the second case, can't you just modify the latter to read from both files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for the `pandas.concat()` function (see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)). Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,0,1,1,2],'B':[3,2,5,3,5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'C':[0,0,1,1,2],'D':[-1,20,-2,33,17]})

df3 = pd.concat((df1,df2),axis=1)

df3.to_csv('myFile.csv')
```

You just have to replace df1 and df2 by your csv files using the `pandas.read_csv` function ([here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)).